# Image on CTkButton flickers when updating it with configure

Tags: python, image, tkinter, customtkinter

I am trying to show the image for a button when hovering over it and hide it when leaving the button with my mouse:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image

window = ctk.CTk()

window.geometry("200x200")

icon = ctk.CTkImage(
    light_image=Image.open("trash.png"),
    dark_image=Image.open("trash.png")
)

def show_icon(event):
    button.configure(image=icon)
    button._draw()

def hide_icon(event):
    button.configure(image=None)
    button._draw()

button = ctk.CTkButton(
    window,
    text="",
    image=None,
    fg_color="white",
    hover_color="white",
    width=36,
)

button.pack()

button.bind("<Enter>", show_icon)
button.bind("<Leave>", hide_icon)

window.mainloop()
```

It works, but the icon is constantly flickering when I have my mouse over the button even when I dont move the mouse.

Does someone know why this is happening?

Edit: It only flickers when I am hovering over the image in the button itsself. When my mouse is anywhere else over the button everything is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hide the icon you do this

```
    button.configure(image=None)
```

which reveals the underlying button and produces an `<Enter>` event.

Produce a same-size blank icon and do this when hiding

```
    button.configure(image="blank.png")
```

which will prevent the generation of spurious events.

Comment: Ah thanks that works :) Do you also know why the hover color doesn't appear anymore when I now hover over it and the image gets shown? Can't you have both an image and the hover color?